# dotnet core build <CopyToOutputPathectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputPathectory> no working

Tags: .net, .net-core, csproj

I am playing with dotnet core, I started a (very) simple blog project (using NancyFx and EF core).
All is working well except view resources copying at build time. My cproj specifies the following :

```
<Content Include="views\demo\*;views\blog\*">
    <CopyToOutputPathectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputPathectory>
</Content>
```

but when running dotnet build my view/* files are not copied to bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0 as i expect. Full app code is available at https://github.com/b3b00/NaApp

Is this featurenot working as I expect or Am i missing something ?
For now my only "workaround" is to manually copy those files

thanks for your help

Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. It should be `CopyToOutputDirectory` not `CopyToOutputPathectory`.

Comment: thanks very much natemcaster ! i havent the time to  correct itright now but it will surely do the job. such a stupid error , thanks again